# Xcode service option is missing in the Services list of Server app

Tags: xcode-server

I have Xcode 9.2 and Server app 5.5 both installed. When I opened Server app, i couldn't find the Xcode option to setup xcode.

I have tried re-installing the xcode after the server app setup. But it still doesn't show up.

[Server app Services list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LrmF.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: OS X server no longer has the bots option, it is now in Xcode itself.  Go to preferences menu and you’ll see it

Comment: @bolnad Thanks for the update.